# Return substring in array with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following string, eg: `'Hello [owner], we could not contact by phone [phone], it is correct?'`.

Regex would like to return in the form of array, all that is within `[]`. Inside the bracket will only alpha characters.

Return:

```
$array = [
  0 => '[owner]',
  1 => '[phone]'
];
```

How should I proceed to have this return in php?

Comment: You tagged this question `preg-match-all` -- the documentation for that function has useful examples. Did you try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$text = 'Hello [owner], we could not contact by phone [phone], it is correct?';
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [owner]
    [1] => [phone]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the end goal of all of this is that you want to replace the `[placeholder]`s with some other text, so use `preg_replace_callback` instead:

```
<?php
$str = 'Hello [owner], we could not contact by phone [phone], it is correct?';

$fields = [
  'owner' => 'pedrosalpr',
  'phone' => '5556667777'
];

$str = preg_replace_callback('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', function($matches) use ($fields) {
  if (isset($fields[$matches[1]])) {              
    return $fields[$matches[1]];                    
  }
  return $matches[0];              
}, $str);        

echo $str;
?>
```

Output:

```
Hello pedrosalpr, we could not contact by phone 5556667777, it is correct?
```